# How to send deauth packets from osx?

Tags: wifi, macos

`aireplay-ng` is not available for Mac OSX. How can I inject frames into the network? I am only concerned with sending deauth packets.

Comment: You can also use Scapy which is a Python packet forger.

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT: Kismac2 is also no longer being maintained however the current build still works on OSX High Sierra

Kismac2 has a very large set of functions, including deauth.

https://github.com/IGRSoft/KisMac2/blob/master/README.md

Although kismac-ng (a previous incarnation) has been abandoned, kismac2 is now the tool of choice for most pentesters and wardrivers who need a quick overview of networks, and several attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile aircrack suite from source code. A [guide](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_aircrack-ng_from_source) is in the aircrack-ng webpage

Or if you don't want to compile you can [download it from Macports](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_on_mac_osx) as said in the same webpage

Comment: aircrack-ng is available for mac, but aireplay-ng is not. That's why its not working.

Comment: @AdityaChaudhary The  [source code in their svn repository](https://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/src/) includes all the tools in the `aircrack-ng` suite, including `aireplay-ng`. Compile it and it should work

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark What is not working?

Comment: It just doesn't work. Have you tried it on a recent mac?

Bettercap works

Comment: @Mark If it's a problem with `aireplay-ng` you should report it to the maintainer. Last time I had to use it worked fine, but it was a long time ago

Comment: I'm reporting it here to save people spending time compiling it only to find it doesn't work.

Comment: `brew install aircrack-ng`

Answer (score -1):

To give you an answer you could work with, I uploaded my Kali image to the hub. Just start docker (in our case docker engine for OSX) and give it a shot. It works.

`docker run --name pen-tests -ti --net="host" --privileged -h kali fitz4815162342/pen-tests /bin/bash`

Comment: just general advice never run some random docker image from the internet, especially a privileged docker image.